# How to store array in object for my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to push items to array.

I have something like

```
var t = [];
items = [
    {id:123, name:'test1', category:'toy'},
    {id:123, name:'test2', category:'cookies'},
    {id:789, name:'test3', category:'toy'},
    {id:155, name:'test4', category:'pen'},
    {id:155, name:'test5', category:'eraser'}
];

items.map(function(item) {    
    t[item.id].push(item.category);
    //do other things
})
```

The end result I need

```
t = [
    {123: ['toy', 'cookies']},
    {789: ['toy']},
    {155: ['pen', 'eraser']}
]
```

I am getting can't read property 'push' of undefined. 
Is there a better to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `t[item.id]` is an `Object`. `push()` is a method of `Array`, not `Object`.

Comment: I understand the error. but was wondering if there is a solution for this

Comment: Why is your desired output an array of hashes keyed by the id? I don't see the purpose of the array. Couldn't it just be a single hash keyed by the id, since every key would be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `t` as an object instead of a array, each object will have a array value which also must be assigned before, Try:

```js
var t = {}, items = [
    {id:123, name:'test1', category:'toy'},
    {id:123, name:'test2', category:'cookies'},
    {id:789, name:'test3', category:'toy'},
    {id:155, name:'test4', category:'pen'},
    {id:155, name:'test5', category:'eraser'}
];

items.forEach(function(item){
  !t[item.id] && (t[item.id] = []);
  t[item.id].push(item.category)
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(t));
document.write("<br><b>" + t[123] + "</b>"); //<= Get items by ID

//In your case
var tArray = [];
for(var id in t){
  var obj = {};
  obj[id] = t[id];
  tArray.push(obj)
}
document.write("<br>" + JSON.stringify(tArray));
```

Comment: the result should be an array ... `t = [ ... ]`

Comment: @NinaScholz Then you can to loop the object, to store as an array

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `t` is an **empty** array. In your mapping function, you are referencing an element in `t` that does not exist (i.e. `t[item.id]`). Since, `t` is empty, `t[item.id]` will always return `undefined`. This is why `push()` does not work. The error you get is trying to tell you this. You need to make `t[item.id]` an array before you can `push()` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in the map if t contained the id, if so append a category otherwise push a new obj

```
    items.map(function(item) {   
    var cid=-1;
    for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
        if(t[i].id==item.id)
            cid=i;
    }
    var obj={};
    if(cid==-1){
        obj.id=item.id;
        obj.category=[];
        obj.category.push(item.category);
        t.push(obj);  
    }else{
        obj=t[cid];
        obj.category.push(item.category);
        t[cid]=obj;
    }
//do other things
});
```

Answer (score 0):

t[item.id] would suggest the idth element of the array t

this code does the job:

```
var t = [];
var j = [];
items = [
    {id:123, name:'test1', category:'toy'},
    {id:123, name:'test2', category:'cookies'},
    {id:789, name:'test3', category:'toy'},
    {id:155, name:'test4', category:'pen'},
    {id:155, name:'test5', category:'eraser'}
];

items.forEach(function(item) {
  var isIn = false;
  j.forEach(function(elt, i) {
    if(item.id == elt)
      isIn = true;
  });
  if(!isIn)
    j.push(item.id);
  isIn = false;
});
j.forEach(function(id) {
  var elts = [];
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.id == id)
      elts.push(item);
  });
  var obj = {};
  obj.id = id;
  obj.category = [];
  elts.forEach(function(elt) {
    obj.category.push(elt.category);
  });
  t.push(obj);
});
console.log(t);
    //do other things
```